# MDT/WDS Windows 7 deployment fails

Tags: windows-7, wds, mdt

I've been following the tutorials to deploy a fresh instance of Windows 7 via MDT/WDS.  I've injected the proper drivers, configured the sequences, but every system fails at 50% of "installing OS" with return code -2147467359 0x80004005.

Research on "unknown errors" is proving unsuccessful.

Advice is welcome.  Logs can be provided

Comment: Are you using Linux as the PXE back end? Also can you provide me with the bdd log for the mdt deployment? Here are various log locations https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7cbd22f-3a79-43a0-97b7-88503396b89a/mdt-log-file-locations?forum=mdt

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Determined that it was the Dell storage drivers in the boot image that were killing everything. Removed them, and success.

Now working on VS2015 deployment via MDT :)

Comment: Congrats and good luck!